# Getting content from html

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I want to download content from html like this. It is ember app.

```
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

When i click inspect element, it showing something like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="app" class="emeber-application">
  <div id="ember344" class="ember-view">
  <div class="main header>..</div>
  ....
</body>
```

So, is it possible (and how) to get content of this and write it to file, using JavaScript? Not manually copy and paste.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Can you tell how to do it?

Comment: *"...is it possible to get content of this and write it to file, using JavaScript?"* Yes. But probably not from a browser. Browser-based JavaScript has two significant restrictions:

Comment: 1. You can't access content from other *origins* (loosely, domains) unless the other origin expressly allows access. (This is called the Same Origin Policy; the way origins grant exceptions is via Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.) If your origin is allowed to access the content from the other origin, you'd do that via "ajax" (probably with the `XMLHttpRequest` object or a library wrapper for it like jQuery's `$.ajax`).

Comment: 2. You can't access the file system of the machine the browser is running on, for security reasons. You can provide a file, but the user is the one who tells the browser to write it to disk, and your code will have no idea where it was written.

Comment: Outside of a browser, you can use any JavaScript environment with reasonable HTTP and file features (and possibly a headless browser tool like PhantomJS), such as NodeJS, or the Java JVM (JavaScript is available for the Java JVM, even though Java and JavaScript are completely different languages).

Comment: Separately, it looks like the content you want to grab is *dynamically generated*, which means just using ajax to query it won't give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

As T.J. Crowder said it is not possible to save file from the browser directly.
In the other hand it is possible to download file using data URIs:

```
function download() {
    var text = document.querySelector('body').innerHTML;
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', "download.html");

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```